# Deleting conversions causing ambiguous overload?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Our code is multi-platform. I use MSVC and my colleagues use Clang or GCC.

One of our classes has a pointer conversion, which always returns non-`nullptr`. I found a problem due to to accidentally using it in boolean expressions, which would always return `true`. So, I deleted the boolean conversion operator.

This worked perfectly for me (and actually revealed ten other places in our program where we were doing this), but my colleagues could no longer compile due to ambiguous overloads.

Here's the situation:

```cpp
class Thingy
{
public:
  operator const double * () const
  {
    return xyz;
  }

  operator bool () const = delete;

private:
  double xyz[3];      
};

void func(const double *d)
{
}

void func(unsigned int i)
{
}

int main()
{
  Thingy a;
  func(a);
}
```

On MSVC, `func(const double *d)` is called, which I would expect. However, on GCC, it fails as follows:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:27:9: error: call of overloaded 'func(Thingy&)' is ambiguous
   func(a);
         ^
<source>:16:6: note: candidate: 'void func(const double*)'
 void func(const double *d)
      ^~~~
<source>:20:6: note: candidate: 'void func(unsigned int)'
 void func(unsigned int i)
      ^~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

If you take out the `operator bool () const = delete;`, it works fine on GCC, but you then don't have protection from the following:

```cpp
Thingy b /* = callSomeFunction()*/;
if (!b)
{
  // whoops! never enters here! Would be nice for this to be a compiler error.
}
else
{
  // do something with the valid Thingy
}
```

We think that on GCC/Clang the ambiguity is between calling `func(const double*)` with the conversion to `const double*` and calling `func(unsigned int)` with a conversion to `bool`, even though the conversion to `bool` is explicitly invalid.

Why is this the case? Why does MSVC allow it? Is there any way we can get the desired effect, other than perhaps `#ifdef _MSVC_VER`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what the "desired effect" is?

Comment: When you say “it works fine on gcc” when the bool conversion operator is not deleted, have you confirmed the correct overload of `func` is actually being called?

Comment: @M.M The desired effect is that `Thingy x; if(x)` and `Thingy y = someFunction(); bool okSoFar = y; okSoFar |= someOtherValidation();` should both cause compiler errors, and if there is a function overload that takes both a `double *` and something that can be converted from a `double *` (such as `unsigned int`) that the compiler uses the `double *` overload without complaint.

Comment: @JohnDrouhard yes, godbolt.org says that `func(double const *)` is what is called. (I don't know how long the share links last for, but: https://godbolt.org/g/fncEpx)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to declare the operator bool as `explicit`. Used as a condition in a `if`, `while` or `for`, the explicit operator would be called, but ignored for implicit conversions on function calls.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78dd309602295e79

Comment: I think they want to get an error for attempted implicit conversion to bool

Comment: @M.M If I understood the question correctly they want the error when the object is used in an if-statement, which isn't an implicit conversion, it calls explicit operators.

Comment: This will also error when used as an operand of `!` or `&&` or `||`, or as the first operand of `?:`, which is a good thing for this type.

Comment: The ideal would be to error for both implicit and explicit conversions, but explicit at least gives us more protection than we have at the moment.